# how to get name of branch that i created new branch as a clone of it

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, branch

i am using bitbucket and for example i have 3 branches :

1. **master**
2. **stage**
3. **prod**

then i created new branch from **stage** (clone) and i name it **new_branch**

how can i know after a long time which branch that '**new_branch**' is created from ? i mean how i can know that '**new_branch**' is a clone of '**stage**' not '**prod**' or '**master**' ?

any help will be highly appreciated ...

Comment: You can't from a Git point of view, because a branch is not a "clone" of another branch. Unless Bitbucket keeps a record of how the branch was originally created, I don't know that.

Comment: A branch is only a pointer to the most recent commit in that branch. It does not keep track of where it was originally created.